# How can I output a text string when my dynamically built form is empty?

Tags: forms

I have a form that is dynamically built. It renders a list of check boxes, but sometimes there are none to render - it is empty. In this circumstance, instead of the forms `#titles` with nothing below them being rendered, I'd like to output `t('None')`. For the type `#tableselect` the option seems to exist: `#empty`, but not for checkboxes or any other type. How can I acheive this? Thanks.

Code added:

```
    // Form defintion.
    $form['posts'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Member responses to:'),
        '#options' => $options['post'],
    );
    $form['terms'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Posts tagged with:'),
        '#options' => $options['term'],
    );
    $form['groups'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Group posts for:'),
        '#options' => $options['group'],
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Remove'),
    );
    return $form;
```

I tried at the bottom:

```
if(empty($options)) {
  return t('None');
} else {
  return $form
}
```

...but this threw an error.

Comment: Shouldn't you just not build the checkboxes that are empty? In your custom module or what not shouldn't you make sure there is data before adding it to the form?

Comment: The check boxes are not build - there are none to build. The title of the form is built and rendered - besides I want to output a text string instead of a form. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should return a form element (if you are using `drupal_get_form`). What you could do is return a `markup` element within the form.

```
if(empty($options)) {
    $form['empty'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => t('None'),
    );
} else {
    $form['posts'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Member responses to:'),
        '#options' => $options['post'],
    );
    $form['terms'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Posts tagged with:'),
        '#options' => $options['term'],
    );
    $form['groups'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => t('Group posts for:'),
        '#options' => $options['group'],
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Remove'),
    );
}

return $form
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the code before/after and exact context in which you are using it., but this could work for you:

```
if(empty($options)) {
  $form['empty']['#markup'] = t('None');
}
else {
  // Form defintion.
  $form['posts'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => t('Member responses to:'),
      '#options' => $options['post'],
  );
  $form['terms'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => t('Posts tagged with:'),
      '#options' => $options['term'],
  );
  $form['groups'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => t('Group posts for:'),
      '#options' => $options['group'],
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Remove'),
  );
}
return $form;
```